# SMTP error:No outbound route between this site and the Internet on Port 465

Tags: wordpress, smtp, postman

i am using Postman SMTP in wordpress and getting this error.

✅  Port 443 can be used with the Mandrill API.
✅  Port 443 can be used with the Gmail API.
✅  Port 443 can be used with the SendGrid API.
❌ No outbound route between this site and the Internet on Port 465.
❌ No outbound route between this site and the Internet on Port 587.
❌ No outbound route between this site and the Internet on Port 25.
A test with "No" Service Available indicates one or more of these issues:

Your web host has placed a firewall between this site and the Internet
The SMTP hostname is wrong or the mail server does not provide service on this port
Your PHP configuration is preventing outbound connections
Your WordPress configuration is preventing outbound connections

and here is screenshot 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFJLL.png)

Please help and let me know what is issue.
Thankyou